# Unity 2d - rigidbody rotating Z axis if hit something

Tags: c#, unity

I have problem with my player. I use rigidbody2D on my player and I had fixed rotation on Z, but now i need use rotation with some of my root animation. Ok, i enabled it, but when my player hit something (for example NPC, wall, ...), rotates on the Z axis and falls off. Can you help me? Thanks and sorry for my mistakes.
[image]

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We will need you to provide your code to help you.

Comment: Is it betteer ?

Comment: when you say "rotates on the Z axis and falls off", what falls off of what?

Comment: Rigidbody - player rotates on Z and falls like human in real world falls - the head falls to the ground